# Is there a way to 'handle' Environment.FailFast?

Tags: .net, error-handling

So our application has a nice, central exception handler, wherein the details of exceptions are logged, generic windows are displayed to the users, and shutdown happens in a nice graceful way.  However, we now have a 3rd party component that, from time to time, (and potentially for perfectly valid reasons) calls Environment.FailFast.  This blows our app out of the water, and looks quite terrible to our users.  Is there some way to handle Environment.FailFast in an elegant way?

Comment: These kind of problems are solved the old-fashioned way.  Pick up the phone and give them a call.  Work something out so you can at least configure it so it won't do that anymore.  Endlessly preferred over something desperate like running it in a separate process.

Comment: @HansPassant Cannot +1 that enough!

Comment: The third party has source-code available; it seems they don't DIRECTLY call Environment.FailFast... rather... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757164/under-what-circumstances-could-uielement-updatelayout-call-environment-failfas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a way, according to the various entries in MSDN this is a hard termination of the process. Any code you would create to handle this would reside in the process. It also doesn't run finally blocks or any pending finalizers, so I'm guessing wouldn't provide any events or hooks in order to allow custom code to run. In a way this makes sense, otherwise it might not fail "fast" and it argues to only use in cases of extreme process corruption.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289241

I see <strike>two</strike> three options:

1. Send a request to the vendor to change the code and remove this call.
2. Find a new vendor.
3. As suggested by @RB. farm the use of this DLL into a new process so the core application process remains safe. I did this once, mega headache but "it worked". **I would only advise this if you cannot utilise suggestions 1 or 2!**

Quote from MSDN:

> This method terminates a process without running any active
>   try/finally blocks or finalizers.
>
> The FailFast method writes the message string to the Windows
>   Application event log, creates a dump of your application, and then
>   terminates the current process. The message string is also included in
>   error reporting to Microsoft.
>
> Use the FailFast method instead of the Exit method to terminate your
>   application if the state of your application is damaged beyond repair,
>   and executing your application's try/finally blocks and finalizers
>   will corrupt program resources.

Comment: My experience is that calling `Environment.FailFast()` will cause the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event to be synchronously invoked. However, this apparently cannot be used to avoid the inevitable "ugly" Windows dialog that the poster is trying to avoid. I even tried putting a `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` into that even handler, but I still got the Windows message.

Comment: There are three more ways to fix this: ① `FailFast` calls a Win32 function internally which can be hooked (the hook needs to be written in C++ native though); ② you can create your own CLR host, isn't even that hard, it solves @DaveTillman's issue (you can prevent the dialog); ③ you can remove the offending code if the DLL is not signed using weaving, i.e. with [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the 3rd party code in a new process.

A simple way of doing this would be wrapping the 3rd-party code up in an executable, and than launching this using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx).

Note that I can't find documentation what the error level will be following FailFast. When I tested it the value I got was `-2146232797`...

Comment: I had to do this when the only available solution to a problem was from a 3rd party vendor. It was slightly unstable and used to crash the entire process. I would advise this only if you cannot find an alternative vendor or solution - as this also imposes the use of Inter-Process Communication (or some other mechanism for talking across process boundaries) if you need the code to talk to each other. I did this, mega headache, but granted it worked.

Comment: From the .NET source code, `-2146232797` is [`COR_E_FAILFAST`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/6f3e349b80f713d902e0d47eac1948f6c6a4296d/src/pal/prebuilt/inc/corerror.h#L780), which [`Environment.FailFast`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/7045ca7a6de381b382a709dc0a61f49ca713d160/src/classlibnative/bcltype/system.cpp#L623) uses as the exit code. Not MSDN documentation, but at least something to explain the value.