# Under what circumstances could UIElement.UpdateLayout() call Environment.FailFast?

Tags: .net, wpf, error-handling

So I have a control which, in response to its items being changed, calls UpdateLayout().  This results in a stack trace that looks like the following:

> Description: The application requested process termination through
>   System.Environment.FailFast(string message). Message: Unrecoverable
>   system error. Stack:    at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String) 
>   at MS.Internal.Invariant.FailFast(System.String, System.String)    at
>   MS.Internal.Invariant.Assert(Boolean, System.String)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.GetWindowMinMax()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()    at

Clearly, under some circumstances, GetWindowMinMax() is failing an Assert() of some sort, which is causing an call to Environment.FailFast.  What conditions can I check before calling UpdateLayout to ensure that these circumstances do not occur in order to avoid encountering this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take Reflector and peek at the code for `GetWindowMinMax`. This is the assert:

```
Invariant.Assert (!this.IsCompositionTargetInvalid, 
    "IsCompositionTargetInvalid is supposed to be false here") ;
```

So it would appear that your window is not really created as a Win32 window yet or its Win32 window is already destroyed.

Comment: This seems to be true;  however, how can you address the race condition between checking that the window is not closing and someone closing the window just before UpdateLayout runs?

Comment: Where is this call to UpdateLayout made? Can you provide more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

I have a consistent repro for this:

```
        hwndSource = new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource(p);
        this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        hwndSource.RootVisual = this;
```

Setting RootVisual to a hidden window will trigger FailFast.